# Не получается запушить Docker Образ

Tags: docker, push

При выполнении команды docker push у меня начинается загрузка образа на docker hub, но сначала он загружается очень медленно, скорость примерно 100-200 Кб/сек при моей скорости интернета 40 Мб/сек. Потом загрузка прекращается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Напишу текстом подчеркнутую строку, которую мне вывела командная строка:

```
write tcp 192.168.65.3:53348->192.168.65.1:3128: use of closed network connection
```

Раньше у меня не было такой проблемы, уже загружал образ такого же размера на Docker hub.

Как можно решить проблему и нормально загрузить образ?

Файл docker-compose.yml, если пригодится:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9.13

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        cmake libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev protobuf-compiler \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=index.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0

RUN pip install setuptools==59.8.0 && pip install numpy==1.19.2
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Comment: `192.168.65.1:3128` порт 3128 намекает, что загрузка осуществляется через прокси сервер (скорей всего squid). Скорей всего он установлен как "прозрачный" прокси в вашей сети. Возможно на нем проблемы с загрузкой

Comment: как можно решить эту проблему с загрузкой?

Comment: обратиться к сисадмину вашей сети, чтобы он посмотрел логи на прокси, что там происходит